Volume of logarithmic horns
I have been working on this set of problems involving logarithmic horns (basically just logarithmic spirals in $3$ dimensions); however I have been struggling with the final question of the set of problems involving a calculation of the volume for $\theta \in (-\infty, 0]$.
My problem is that in order to find $dV$ I am told to find $dA \cdot dw$ which I have got in a form that doesn't appear to be a traditional vector. I used the equation $\frac{dw}{d\theta} = wb$ to get that $w = w_0\,e^{b\theta}$ and substituting and rearranging to get
$$
dw = w_0\,be^{b\theta}\,d\theta.
$$
How could this be turned into a form that can be used in a dot product? My equation for $dA$ is in parametric form which I got using the scalar product and is true for when $\theta$ is set to $0$ in all terms except $e^{b\theta}$.
Also, because the $dw$ term has $d\theta$ in it and the $dA$ term also has $d\theta$, wouldn't any integral formed be integrated w.r.t. $(d\theta)^2$?
Any help would be greatly appreciated and I'd be happy to link any answers to previous parts to save you the time of working through them. (e.g., equations for $dr_\theta$ and $dr_\alpha$ or parametric equations for the log horn). I'm also happy to reword anything if it doesn't wholly make sense.
Here are the answers to part A:
\begin{align}
X(\alpha) &= \bigl(r_0 + w\cos(\alpha)\bigr) \cos(\alpha) \\
Y(\alpha) &= b\bigl(r_0\cos(\alpha) + w\bigr) \\
Z(\alpha) &= \bigl(r_0 + w\cos(\alpha)\bigr) \sin(\alpha) 
\end{align}
Problems linked below

The problem I haven't solved
Related problem I have solved
And another

I have solved every other question on this topic on this website but didn't want to spam links. That's every 7.6 question and basically every university c1-3 question.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I have also struggled with this question. No idea how to find the dw vector. Is it possible to just differentiate the log horn vector with against to w to get dw? Have you solved it though?

This is a comment, not an answer

That definitely could work, ill give that a go when I get home as i havent tried this question in a few weeks.
